# Dnsmasq homestead & osx stopped working for subdomains

Tags: macos, vagrant, subdomain, homestead, dnsmasq

Until chrome just blocked me from using my `http://development.app` domain, everything was working. My laptop suddenly restarted and then development domain (`http://development.app`) started asking for SSL.

So I tried to move to `http://development.local` (and also tried `.test` but couldn't make it work also - but everything was working on `.app`)

In my osx:

```
nano /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf

address=/.local/192.168.10.10  // also tried: address=/local/192.168.10.10
```

Then I restarted with:

```
sudo launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq
sudo launchctl start homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq
```

Then in `vagrant ssh`:

```
sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf

local=/development.local/
domain=development.local
address=/development.local/127.0.0.1
```

In my hosts, I have:

```
192.168.10.10 development.local
192.168.10.10 *.development.local
```

Now, http://development.local works however http://test.development.local doesn't however, before this change it was working with http://test.development.app . Going the url now returns me:

> This site can’t be reached
>   test.development.local’s server IP address could not be found

I am not sure what it means at all but

```
dig test.development.local @127.0.0.1

> test.development.local.   0   IN  A   192.168.10.10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot about this step that I did earlier:

```
nano /etc/resolver/local

nameserver 127.0.0.1
```